# /t not working in C# console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

when i put \t in the `console.writelin()` it doesn't work

```
 if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("|{0}|\t|{1}|\t|{2}|\t|{3}|\t|{4}|", reader.GetName(0),
                    reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2), reader.GetName(3), reader.GetName(4));

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                Console.WriteLine("|{0}|\t|{1}|\t|{2} EGP|\t|{3} EGP|\t|{4}|", reader.GetString(0),
                    reader.GetInt32(1), reader.GetInt32(2), reader.GetInt32(3), reader.GetString(4));
            }
        }
```

the result is ::

```
    |Product Name|  |Quantity|      |price per item |       |Total| |Code|
|a|     |1|     |0 EGP| |1 EGP| |12|
```

even when i use `{0,10}` or `{0,-10}` it is not working

[image: the spacing is not equal and this is not happens when get data from database it happen also if i gust put \t in console.writeline]

thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at string padding instead of tabulation

Comment: It looks like it's working, it may not be doing what you want but a \t character is not a "just do what I want"-character

Comment: how it can work but the space between " |Total| |Code| " not equal to
" |Quantity|      |price per item |"

Comment: What output are you expecting? It is working.

Comment: Give the guy a break! It's pretty obvious what he's asking. If you think it can be expressed better then you could always help by editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's work.
You sould imagine tabs as columns markers. So when you put a \t you are saying to Console: jump to the next available column mark. In your header 'Product Name' has revased the first tab column, so when Console process \t, it jumps to 2nd column. Instead, in the data, 'a' is small enought and can jump to the 1st column.

This will output with correct format:

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("|{0,-15}|", "Product Name"));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("|{0,-15}|", "a"));
```

You can see it working at http://rextester.com/TUVX20333

Answer (score 2):

## Q

What does the `\t` do?

## A

It moves the cursor to the next column that is a multiple of 8.

This is exactly what is happening in your example. Maybe not what you wanted but definitely what you asked for. ;)

Answer (score 1):

\t really works here. But you are expecting something else. If you can mention what kind of output you are expecting. It would be easy to help.

Edit: The below code would create the header of the table as you have expected. Adjust the second number inside the {} to suit your column width.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("|{0,-20}|{1,-20}|{2,-20}|{3,-20}|{4,-20}|", "Product Name", "Quantity", "Price per item", "Total", "Code"));
```

Comment: i need to make a table to show the output and i need to make space equal

Answer (score 0):

A stopgap measure, if you know the length of your columns, is to use `string.PadRight`. BUT it is messy:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
    ("|" + reader.GetString(0) + "|").PadRight(20, ' '),
    ("|" + reader.GetInt32(1) + "|").PadRight(20, ' ')
    ("|" + reader.GetInt32(2) + "EGP|").PadRight(20, ' ')
    ("|" + reader.GetInt32(3) + "EGP|").PadRight(20, ' ')
    ("|" + reader.GetString(4) + "|").PadRight(20, ' '));
```

Although putting that into a separate method is straight forward.

If you really want to use `\t` then you can write a separate method to calculate how many tabs to add. Once again you will need to know the length of each field:

```
string ToTabColumn(string text, int length)
{
    int tabSize = 8; // no easy way of getting environment tab length
    int colSize = text.Length + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceil((double)(length - text.Length) / tabSize));

    return text.PadRight(colSize, '\t');
}
```